# Can we use "before"(as the time adverb) in a past simple sentence?

Tags: past-tense

> We were happy **before**.

> There was a market next to the school **before**.

> I saw a whale **before**.

These are from a grammar book for kids that I'm proofreading, and this part is about "past simple tense". I would like to ask if these sentences are grammatically correct regarding the use of "before." It seems that "before" should be used with perfect tense? Should I make the following changes? Thank you!

> We were happy **then**.

> There was a market next to the school **(sometime ago)**.

> I saw a whale **(sometime ago)**.

Comment: *Before **what**?*

Comment: In my AmE dialect, *There was a market next to the school before" is idiomatic and means "There **used to be** a market next to the school".

Comment: And "We were happy before" would be idiomatic in a conversation between two people who are no longer happy with each other and talking about it, or in a situation where someone is talking about a life-changing event. In other words, it needs a proper context to justify **before**.

Comment: The only sentence that I find truly unidiomatic (because I can't think of a context where it would be idiomatic) is the sentence about the whale. It should be "I have seen a whale before" if the meaning intended is "This is not my first time seeing a whale."

Comment: @FumbleFingers  These sentences don't have the context. They are independent sentences to demonstrate "past simple tense." I got your point! Thanks!

Comment: @TimR Thank you for your clear explanation and giving the context to show the use of "before" is possible. However, these sentences are actually independent sentences. They're simply to demonstrate the past simple tense. I guess if they need so much context to justify them, they're not suitable for the basic demonstration of the tense. After all, the grammar book is for kids who learn the tense for the first time. There could be better sample sentences. Thanks again. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Both (1b) 'We were happy before' and (2b) 'There was a market next to the school before' are acceptable; they are deleted forms, and must be licensed by prior context eg

- (1a) 'The war was a terrible time for our family.'
- (2a) 'A lot of changes were made to the town in the 70s.')

(or 'before' lacks reference).

(3) 'I saw a whale before' sounds improbable to my ears. The independent clause is punctive rather than durative, unlike the situations in (1b) and (2b). 'The mist thickened at around midday, making it impossible to continue our search for wildlife, but I saw a whale before this happened' sounds far more natural than the deleted form. 'I've seen a whale before' is far more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation and the example with context. I now see that the use of "before" is a deleted form  and needs to be justified with context. Really appreciate your help!